# Prove that $\exists c\in (a,b):f''(c) = 0$, if there is a secant line that intersects the graph of $f$ on $a,x_0, b$ where $a < x_0 < b$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is an interval, a twice derivable function. Suppose that the secant line through the points $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ with $a,b \in I$ and $a < b$, intercepts the graph of $f$ in a point $(x_0, f(x_0))$, with $a < x_0 < b$. Show that $\exists c \in (a,b): f''(c) = 0$.

---

I think what should be done to prove this is showing that there is $x, y$ such that $f'(x) = f'(y)$, and then conclude that there is $f''(c) = 0$ through Rolle's theorem.

Since the secant line intercepts a point between $a,b$ and $f$ is continuous, it is easy to see that there is $a < x < y < b$ such that $f'(x) = f'(y)$, since it must mean that the graph "goes back in the direction where it came from" and then "heads towards its original direction" again.

I don't know how to write this down formally in a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line segments from $(a, f(a))$ to $(x_0, f(x_0))$ and from $(x_0, f(x_0))$ to $(b, f(b))$ are two parts of the same secant line, and therefore have the same slope:
$$
\frac{f(x_0)-f(a)}{x_0-a} = \frac{f(b)-f(x_0)}{b-x_0} \, .
$$
According to the mean-value theorem, the fraction on the left is equal to $f'(x)$ for some $x \in (a, x_0)$, and the fraction on the right is equal to $f'(y)$ for some $y \in (x_0, b)$. So $f'(x) = f'(y)$ with $x < y$, and it follows that $f''(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (x, y) \subset (a, b)$.

You can also consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - l(x)$ where $l$ is the given secant line. Then $g(a) = g(x_0) = g(b) = 0$. Now apply Rolle's theorem repeatedly to conclude that $g'$ has (at least) two distinct zeros, and $g'' = f''$ has (at least) one zero.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say $g'' = f''$, it happens because $l'(x)$ is constant and therefore $l''(x) = 0$. Right?

Comment: @user: Yes, exactly.